# how to get the path of Asset picked from gallery multi_image_picker2?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, image-gallery

I am using **multi_image_picker2: ^5.0.2**. I just need to upload the selected images to Firebase. How can i get the path of List ? when i use image.name i get the issue:

> 'file.absolute.existsSync()': is not true.

.

**The Code Is:**

```
  var images = <Asset>[].obs;
  await FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('products/$docID')
        .putFile(File(images[0].name??""));
```

Comment: Hi, Is your issue resolved?

Comment: i have usef this library to convert Asset into File
`flutter_absolute_path:
   git:
    url: https://github.com/kornperkus/flutter_absolute_path.git`

Comment: If it has worked for you then you can post it as an answer with a little more explanation so that it helps the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pickedFilename.path**

```
var images = <Asset>[].obs;
 var img= await FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('products/$docID')
        .putFile(File(images[0].name??""));

var imgPath=img.path;
```

Comment: it does not uploaded to firestorage, to do so

Answer (score 0):

```
if (productImage1 != null) {
        final storageReference =
            FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("products/imgname");

        final uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(productImage1!);
        final downloadUrl = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
        imgUrl = await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL();
      }
```

> Here productImage1 contains the path after selecting the image.
> productImage1 = imagefile.path;